# lisp macro expansion: not of type LIST error

Tags: list, macros, lisp, common-lisp

I have a macro that reads a file
that's formatted like this:
(H2O 50)
(O2 50)
...

macro looks like this:

```
(defmacro readextracttolist (filevar filename nthmember listname)
  (list 'progn 
    (list 'defparameter filevar (list 'open filename))
    (list 'loop 'for 'line '= (list 'read filevar 'nil ':eof)
          'until (list 'eq 'line ':eof)
          'do
          ; (list 'print 'line)
          (list 'setq listname (list 'append listname (list 'elt 'line nthmember))))))
```

When I run command:

```
(readextracttolist xx "syminput_0.txt" 0 usedmollist)
```

I get:

```
The value
  H2O
is not of type
  LIST
```

Expecting:

```
list USEDMOLLIST:

(H2O O2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you try to append a single element and not a list to the existing list, as more easily seen after macroxpanding the macro:

```
(macroexpand '(readextracttolist xx "syminput_0.txt" 0 usedmollist))
(PROGN
 (DEFPARAMETER XX (OPEN "syminput_0.txt"))
 (LOOP FOR LINE = (READ XX NIL :EOF)
       UNTIL (EQ LINE :EOF)
       DO (SETQ USEDMOLLIST (APPEND USEDMOLLIST (ELT LINE 0)))))
```

Furthermore, the macro can be made more readable by using `backquote`syntax, where only symbols prefixed by `,` are substitued.  `progn` and `defparameter` can also be replaced by a `let`:

```
(defmacro readextracttolist (filevar filename nthmember listname)
  `(let ((,filevar (open ,filename)))
     (loop for line = (read ,filevar nil :eof)
       until (eq line :eof) do
       (print line)
       (setq ,listname (append ,listname (list (nth ,nthmember line)))))))
```

Also: A macro is probably not needed here, as a function could do the job (e.g by returning a list to be appended to the existing list).

Comment: Serapeum has a handy [`append1`](https://github.com/ruricolist/serapeum/blob/master/REFERENCE.md#append1-list-item) for appending an atom to the end of a list that could be used here Or the old standby of building the list in reverse order via `cons`/`push`/etc. and reversing it when done.

Answer (score 2):

In complement to the other answer, here are some things you could improve in your code:

- you never `close` the file being open, which makes your process keep system resources until it terminates; if you only open and never close your streams you'll eventually hit limits.
- your code makes heavy use of side-effects, which can be fine if run in a script but this is bad style in general. You should try to write mostly functional code to help you manage side-effects only at the points where this is needed.
- you call `append` to add elements at the end of the list, which is linear in time, inside a loop which is also linear in time, ending up with a quadratic algorithm. This will impact performance at some point if your lists are big. Prefer putting element in front of the list (constant time), only to reverse it at the end, to keep a linear time.

You could for example write auxiliary functions. First let's have a package definition for your code:

```
(defpackage :stack-overflow (:use :cl))
(in-package :stack-overflow)
```

Here `map-forms` calls `read`, apply a function and collect them into a list.

```
(defun map-forms (file function)
  (with-open-file (stream file)
    (loop 
      :for line = (handler-case (read stream)
                   (end-of-file () (loop-finish)))
      :collect (funcall function line))))
```

Then you can use this function to collect all the *nth* items from forms being read.

```
(defun extract-nth (file n)
  (map-forms file (lambda (f) (nth n f))))
```

Then, maybe you can add a macro if you need it, but even there I think being explicit is better:

```
(defparameter *second-items*
  (extract-nth "/tmp/first.txt" 1))
```

Then:

```
(setf *second-items* 
  (append *second-items*
          (extract-nth "/tmp/second.txt" 1)))
```